# c# Listview with images column strange behaviour

Tags: c#, listview, multiple-columns

i have a list view in which i load some images from a folder through imagelist control.
when I initialize the form containing the listview i call a method CaricaListBox()

```
private void CaricaListBox()

    {
      if (TxtSourceFolder.FullText != string.Empty)
      {
        LstFile.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(TxtSourceFolder.FullText, "*.*").Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".jpg")))
        {
          Image ImgObj;
          using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(file))
          {
            ImgObj = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
          }
          if (ImgObj.Width > ImgObj.Height)
          {
            imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));
            var LstI = LstFile.Items.Add(" ", imageList.Images.Count - 1); //(Path.GetFileName(file), imageList.Images.Count - 1);
            LstI.SubItems.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
          }
          ImgObj.Dispose();
        }
      }
    }
```

when the form is shown it is as follow 
[image]
and this is what i want.
If press the change folder and i run again the same method to load listbox
i have follow result :
[image]
showing only 1 column.
if i enlarge the listbox view i see as follow :
[image]
so nothing changes

what am I doing wrong ?
any suggestion ?

Tks in advance
Fabrizio

Edited:

```
 private void CaricaListBox()
    {
      if (TxtSourceFolder.FullText != string.Empty)
      {
        LstFile.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(TxtSourceFolder.FullText, "*.*").Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".jpg")))
        {
          var bmpTemp = Image.FromFile(file);
          if (bmpTemp.Width > bmpTemp.Height)
          {
            using (var tempImage = bmpTemp)
            {
              Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(192, 76);
              using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
              {
                g.DrawImage(tempImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
              }
              imageList.Images.Add(bmp);
              var LstI = LstFile.Items.Add(" ", imageList.Images.Count - 1); 
              LstI.SubItems.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
            }
          }
          else bmpTemp.Dispose();
        }
      }
      Conta();
    }
```

it saves memory .. but still have visualization problem when the method is called for the second time.
just noticed that if i call method while form is not yet drawn, it shows 2 columns, if i call method when the form is already drawn, i see 1 column

Fabrizio

Comment: |Why are you opening the image twice? (`new Bitmap(file)` and `Image.FromFile(file)`) and why are you creating a clone (`ImgObj = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);`) just to compare width and height?

Comment: You need to dispose of all those Bitmaps you create. Also, dispose of each object you have added to the ImageList before re-filling it, or dispose of the ImageList itself and create a new one. Set `ColorDepth = Depth32Bit` and  `ImageSize` to exactly what you need there.

Comment: I modified my method .. no more opening twice, reduce memory amount used, but the visualization problem still persists